# Scala Type Mismatch underlying type

Tags: scala

I'm writing methods to convert `Set[Tuple2[String, String]]` to `String` and vice versa.
I'm saving the string value as v1,v2#v3,v4#v5,v6
In order to fill the `Set` I'm splitting the string by ',' and in order to extract the values I'm **trying** to split each value by '#' but i receive

> type mismatch: found: x.type (with underlying type Array[String]

The code I tried using is

```
val x = overwriters.split("#")
for(tuple <- x) {
  tuple.split(",")
}
```

The returned type of split is an array of String so it is not clear to me why i cannot split each member of the returned array

Comment: What is overwriters ? Is it string or Array of string ?

Comment: You're not doing a yield, so your `for` statement results in nothing useful. Also, please post a complete example, as `val overwriters = "5,6#7.8" ;                      
val x = overwriters.split("#") ;
for(tuple <- x) {
  tuple.split(",")
}` works for me

Comment: From some reason it works on scala console but cannot compile on sbt

Comment: Works in the worksheet too. So I think there's something more to it. Are they different scala versions?

Answer (score 2):

```
overwrites.split("#").map(_.split(",")).map(x=> (x(0),x(1))).toSet
```

This will achieve the same in little more idiomatic way.

Comment: Or even `overwriters.split("#").map{x=> val Array(a,b) = x.split(","); (a,b)}.toSet` or `overwriters.split("#").map{ _.split(",") match { case Array(a,b) => (a,b)}}.toSet`

Comment: Or for the lulz: `Set(for {
    x <- overwriters.split("#");
    Array(a, b)  = x.split(",")
  } yield (a, b))`

Comment: or `(for (x <- overwriters split "#"; Array(a,b) = x split ",") yield (a,b)) toSet`

Comment: @Paul, LRLucena lets head over to a three way code shoot out. Mexican style.

Answer (score 2):

`tuple.split(",")` returns an array of two elements. You need to convert it to a tuple.

```
val overwriters ="v1,v2#v3,v4#v5,v6"              
val x = overwriters.split("#").toSet
for(tuple <- x) yield {
  val t = tuple.split(",")
  (t(0),t(1))
}
```

Comment: I went on another direction, using a different structure. It is just interesting why the first approach doesn't work

Comment: The first approach didn't work because your `split` returns an `Array`, as stated here by @LRLucena.  You can convert those `Arrays` into a `Tuple` using this answer.